# como obtener un enlace(link) con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Hola soy nuevo en programacion web y necesito ayuda con este ejercicio porfvor
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

yo hice este codigo el cual solo me arroja un link de los 3 que necesito y no se a que se debe por favor ayuda

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>ACA3 punto 3</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function getlink()
    {
        var l = document.getElementById("milink");
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= l.href;

        var m = document.getElementById("milinkdos");
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= m.href;

        var n = document.getElementById("milinktres");
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= n.href;
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><a id="milink" href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a></p>
    <p><a id="milinkdos" href="http://es-la.facebook.com/">Facebook</a></p>
    <p><a id="milinktres" href="http://www.uniremington.edu.co/manizales/">Uniremington</a></p>
    <p id="result"></p>
    <p><imput type="button" onclick="getlink()" value="ok!">ver direcciones url</imput></p>
</body>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que cada que "agregas" un enlace sobrescribes el contenido del *div* y deberías [concatenar](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings#concatenando_cadenas):

```
    // Limpiar contenido y agregar enlace
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= l.href;
    // Concatenar salto de línea y segundo enlace
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += '<br>' + m.href;
    // Concatenar salto de línea y tercer enlace
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += '<br>' + n.href;
```

Sin embargo, hay una mejor forma de lograrlo y es usando [plantillas de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) que te permiten generar cadenas e incluir variables sin tener que abrir y cerrar comillas, dejando un código más legible:

```js
    function getlink() {
        // Definir variables con let
        let l = document.getElementById("milink");
        let m = document.getElementById("milinkdos");
        let n = document.getElementById("milinktres");
        
        // Asignar contenido, separando con salto de línea
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = `${l.href}<br>${m.href}<br>${n.href}`;
    }
```

```html
    <p><a id="milink" href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a></p>
    <p><a id="milinkdos" href="http://es-la.facebook.com/">Facebook</a></p>
    <p><a id="milinktres" href="http://www.uniremington.edu.co/manizales/">Uniremington</a></p>
    <p id="result"></p>
    <p><imput type="button" onclick="getlink()" value="ok!">ver direcciones url</imput></p>
```